Why is Lombok not generating an all-args constructor?
I have a Spring Boot project and I've configured Lombok.
My pom.xml is as follows:
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

I've a DTO class annotated with @AllArgsConstructor from Lombok as follows:
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomerDto {
    String username;
    String password;
}

However when I do a maven clean compile or even maven clean install, the code that's generated (/target/classes/com/example/...) is
public class CustomerDto {
    String username;
    String password;

    public CustomerDto() {
    }
}

There seems to be no all-args constructor and I'm lost about why. Why is this?
I tried running mvn clean install and mvn clean compile. I tried generating a static factory method instead of an all-args constructor using Lombok, and that also doesn't seem to show up in the compiled class.

I'm not sure of the root cause, but the issue is definitely that Lombok is not running, rather than something you're doing wrong with the annotations - I copied the code into my project and the code was generated successfully.

Are you using java22 by any chance? I think they made annotation processing disabled by default.

I'm using Java 17 atm

normally with lombok, it doesn't generate the classes as source-code, but as .class-files, right? Is that a decompiled .class-file or do you use delombok in your configuration and actually want to write source-code?

You'll need to configure the lombok annotation processor in the maven-compiler-plugin
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.16.12</version>
                    </path>                         
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

